# Parse or convert HTML code embedded inside JSON object in the JSON response

Tags: java, json, rest, web-services

I have the following URL :

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&section=0&prop=text&format=json&page=The%20Matrix

which returns a **JSON response** with **HTML code** embedded within a **JSON object** (**See the link**).

How do I **retrieve** details like Actor, Director etc from that HTML part using java?

How do I convert that Html part to JSON using java, if it's possible?

Or is there any way to change the url itself to get the movie data in readable JSON format?

Comment: Can you provide the selectors for actor/director in the embedded? I could not find those strings

Comment: Do you mean the corresponding label names? @Dhrubajyoti

Comment: Yes, where do actor/director appear in the embedded html?

Comment: Starring
Directed By

Comment: I actually copied the html part alone into a file, saved it as html and viewed it in the browser to see the labels..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution using jsoup for parsing HTML and jackson for parsing JSON:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // Extract JSON string
    String body = Jsoup.connect("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&section=0&prop=text&format=json&page=The%20Matrix")
    .ignoreContentType(true).execute().body();
    // Extract HTML string from JSON
    JsonFactory factory = new JsonFactory();
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(factory);
    JsonNode targetNode = mapper.readTree(body).get("parse").get("text").get("*");
    // Generic but fragile function to extract specific details
    Function<String, String> retrieveDetailsOf = detailsOf ->
        Jsoup.parse(targetNode.asText())
                .select(".infobox tr th:contains(" + detailsOf + ") ~ td a[title]")
                .stream().map(e -> e.attr("title")).collect(Collectors.toList()).toString();

    System.out.println(retrieveDetailsOf.apply("Directed by"));
    System.out.println(retrieveDetailsOf.apply("Produced by"));
    System.out.println(retrieveDetailsOf.apply("Music by"));
    System.out.println(retrieveDetailsOf.apply("Starring"));
}
```

Ouput:

```
[The Wachowskis]
[Keanu Reeves, Laurence Fishburne, Carrie-Anne Moss, Hugo Weaving, Joe Pantoliano]
```

Dependencies:

```
implementation("org.jsoup:jsoup:1.12.2")
implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.10.2")
implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.10.2")
```

Just be mindful of the fact that any changes in the content structure will mostly result in breaks. Rather use official movie detail APIs if available.